# If my question is downvoted, do I have to delete it to recover my reputation?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

If my question gets 2 to 3 downvotes without getting an answer, do I have to delete it to maintain my reputation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes it seems hopless, but the major intention of downvotes is mostly to push you to **improve** your question by editing and making your subjects clearer.

Deleting your question will let you regain your rep (there's even a badge for it IIRC), but the downvotes still count for eventually detected frequent bad questions, and doesn't prevent you from being question banned in the future.

Comment: Thank you sir/mam for this information, now i'm too banned for answering any question, their is notification which say that i need 50 reputation to answer the question. By the way thanx for rply :)

Comment: @akashujjwal _"their is notification which say that i need 50 reputation"_ No, that's not an _answer ban_, you most probably tried to answer a _locked_ question, these require a minimum rep of 50 to answer. I'm pretty sure there are other questions coming in you can answer.

Comment: Sounds more like the comment restriction. A protected question limit is 10 on the site. No one can answer locked questions.

Comment: okay now i get it. But may i know why some questions are locked, is those questions are more professional, and if i have the answer for those questions, then can i answer it.

Comment: @MartinSmith Ah, yes. I meant _protected_ of course. But you are right about the min 10.

Comment: @martin smith. yes sir it true that I had try to comment on a question then I get this notification.